# PowerShell Start-Process Not Starting when script called remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to remotely install Octopus Deploy Tentacle to a VM. I have a powershell script that I've written that handles this business for me. It works exactly as expected when I am physically logged into the machine, but when I am remotely executing it on the machine it doesn't run the installer. Every other part of the script works fine though.

The portion of the script that downloads and installs:

```
try{
    $url = "https://octopus.com/downloads/latest/OctopusTentacle64"
    $downloadPath = "$env:TEMP\octopus\"
 
    if (Test-Path $downloadPath) {
        Remove-Item -Path $downloadPath -Recurse -Force
    }
 
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $downloadPath | Out-Null
 
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, "$downloadPath\Octopus.Tentacle.msi")

    Start-Process -FilePath "$downloadPath\Octopus.Tentacle.msi" -ArgumentList "/passive" -Wait -verbose
    Write-Output "Octopus Tentacle Installed."
} catch { throw "error downloading tentacle. try again later."}
```

I am using this to attempt to run the file remotely(edit, copied wrong line):
`Invoke-Command  -ComputerName $vmName -FilePath "\\$vmName\Installers\Install-Calamari.ps1" -Credential $creds -ArgumentList $deployTag, $envID`

What am I missing?